# Mysterious R ggplot error - Error in list2env(members, envir = e)

Tags: r, ggplot2, environment-variables, rstudio, environment

I'm encountering an unexpected error while using a simple ggplot command, and I have exhausted all my web-searches to find a similar issue.

```
qplot(hp,mpg,data=mtcars)

Error in list2env(members, envir = e) : 
  names(x) must be a character vector of the same length as x
```

The same applies when using ggplot...

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp,mpg)) + geom_point()
Error in list2env(members, envir = e) : 
  names(x) must be a character vector of the same length as x
```

I've never had this issue in the past although I am using ggplot after a while.

I'm running R 3.1.1 , any help would be much appreciated!

Updated: sessionInfo

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Australia.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Australia.1252    
LC_MONETARY=English_Australia.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                       
LC_TIME=English_Australia.1252    


attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

   other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_2.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] digest_0.6.8    htmltools_0.2.6 httpuv_1.3.3    jsonlite_0.9.19 mime_0.4
    R6_2.1.1        Rcpp_0.12.2     tools_3.1.1     xtable_1.8-0
```

Cheers

Comment: what's your sessionInfo()..update ggplot2 maybe

Comment: Updated post with sessionInfo()

Comment: Sorry, I think I used the sessionInfo() before loading ggplot, was trying to re-install it.... Updated Sessioninfo above..

I'm still getting the same error though.

Comment: Code works for me with ggplot 1.0.1 but I know it just got an update and hadley said things could break (apparently he's not a fan of backwards compatibility).  I'll update and see if I get the same issue as @Anes_thetize

Comment: The commands work fine for me after updating ggplot2.

Comment: Maybe you can restart R and re-run all the commands.

Comment: I have independently come up with the same issue an hour ago running a script I used to run a few months ago... I am running an up to date ggplot2 package

Comment: So I've updated / restarted / kicked the CPU to no avail.... 
I've reported the issue on ggplot's github page as well...

Comment: @Dason Hadley's a huge fan of backwards compat. There were design flaws in the older ggplot2 codebase that could not be carried forward. Anes: FWIW OS X 10.11.2, R 3.2.3, latest ggplot2 - works perfectly.

Comment: works for me on R-devel, ggplot 2.0.0; *but* I get quite different packages loaded (`sessionInfo()` 'loaded via namespace' when running R --vanilla); "colorspace_1.2-6  scales_0.3.0.9000 plyr_1.8.3        gtable_0.1.2  Rcpp_0.12.2       grid_3.3.0        munsell_0.4.2" ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It works when I updated R to 3.2.3

That required a few administrative requests (work machine) but it's all sorted now.

```
sessionInfo()

R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Australia.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Australia.1252    
LC_MONETARY=English_Australia.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                       LC_TIME=English_Australia.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_2.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] labeling_0.3     colorspace_1.2-6 scales_0.3.0     plyr_1.8.3       
tools_3.2.3      gtable_0.1.2     Rcpp_0.12.2      grid_3.2.3      
[9] munsell_0.4.2
```

Comment: Mark it correct then otherwise it stays around forever as an "unanswered question"